# MySQL hands with `> after attempting to change user password

Tags: mysql

When using MySQL directly (DOS->MySQL) and changing the password for a user with the following...

```
SET PASSWORD FOR ‘annoyinghippie’@'localhost’ = PASSWORD(’1eetpa$$w0rd&’);
```

...MySQL "hangs" and only shows me...

> ```
> `>
> ```

...doing anything results in the same line repeating. Doing a Ctrl+Break exits MySQL back in to DOS.

Is the syntax for the command wrong? I'm pasting this directly from my notes which I only have work code that has worked in the past. The username/password are obviously changed from real client information.

Comment: Looks like you have  mix of curly single quotes (which are invalid) and one proper opening single quote at `'localhost`.  The quote prompt you're seeing is an indication that there's an unclosed quote.  Be careful when copy/pasting commands from the Internet, as they tend to have improper quote characters as converted by CMS software.

Comment: Hooray for other people's horribly written software! >__> Thanks @MichaelBerkowski

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`‘` is not a valid string delimiter. Use `'` instead.